# SQL conditional join with default values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm kinda struggling with this query, I have the following table:

```
setting
-------
id  | name   | value   | type
--------------------------------
1   | title  | Hi      | string
2   | color  | #ff0000 | string

user_setting
-------
id | userId | settingId | value
--------------------------------
1  | 1      | 1         | Hello

user
-------
id | email
1  | foo@test.com
```

I want to run a query that will select all settings for user `1`, but also include the default value, so ideally I get this:

```
id    | default | value
-----------------------
title | Hi      | Hello
color | #ff0000 | null
```

My current query is

```
SELECT  setting.id, setting.name, setting.value,  user_setting.value, user.id
FROM setting
RIGHT JOIN user_setting
    ON setting.id = "user_setting"."settingId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN user
    ON "user_setting"."userId" = user.id
WHERE user.id = 1
```

But this only gives me the values that the user has defined.

EDIT: Updated setting table

Comment: Don't mix left and right joins - it's just too confusing. Actually, stick to left joins - because it's easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: your setting.id is a string?? Is that correct?

Comment: how is the setting table related to any of the other tables?

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes the left join return inner join result. Move that condition to the ON clause to get true left join result.

Comment: your missing the id for setting, please put it before further analysis

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, forgot to add a `name` column to `setting`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`.  But I think your setting is missing a column for `setting_id` (or whatever it is called).  So the table should really be:

```
setting
-------
 id | name     | value   | type
--------------------------------
  1 | title  | Hi      | string
  2 | color  | #ff0000 | string
```

Otherwise `user_settings.setting_id` doesn't refer to anything.  With this column, you want:

```
select s.name, s.value as default, us.value
from setting s left join
     user_setting us
     on us.setting_id = s.id and us.user_id = 1
```

Comment: I agree he left out a column

Comment: While this works, I don't fully understand why my query wasn't working correctly. Is it because I tried to join my `user` table as well?

Comment: @woutr_be . . . Don't mix `left` and `right` joins.  It is hard to follow.  But in your version, the `where` clause is turning the outer joins into inner joins.